# aarch64-poky-linux-gcc: error: : No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, yocto, openembedded, mlpack

I am trying to include mlpack to my yocto build. Without enabling the python bindings my recipe bakes successfully.
But while building the python bindings I get the following error:

```
aarch64-poky-linux-gcc -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall
-Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fPIC
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/git/src
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb/usr/include
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb/usr/include
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/..
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb/usr/include/python2.7 -c /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/sparse_coding.cpp
-o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/sparse_coding.o
-DBINDING_TYPE=BINDING_TYPE_PYX -std=c++11 -march=armv8-a
-mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall
-Wextra -ftemplate-depth=1000 -O3 -fopenmp aarch64-poky-linux-gcc: error: : No such file or directory aarch64-poky-linux-gcc: error: : No such file or directory error: command 'aarch64-poky-linux-gcc' failed with exit status 1 src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_sparse_coding.dir/build.make:60: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_sparse_coding' failed make[2]: *** [src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_sparse_coding] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory '/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build' CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6651: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_sparse_coding.dir/all' failed make[1]: *** [src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_sparse_coding.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-36.2.7-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py:350: UserWarning: The version specified ('3.0.x') is an invalid version, this may not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI. Please see PEP 440 for more details. running build_ext cythoning /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/preprocess_split.pyx to /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/preprocess_split.cpp building 'mlpack.preprocess_split' extension aarch64-poky-linux-gcc
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall
-Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fPIC
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/git/src
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb/usr/include
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb/usr/include
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/..
-I/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb/usr/include/python2.7 -c /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/preprocess_split.cpp
-o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/preprocess_split.o
-DBINDING_TYPE=BINDING_TYPE_PYX -std=c++11 -march=armv8-a
-mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall
-Wextra -ftemplate-depth=1000 -O3 -fopenmp aarch64-poky-linux-gcc: error: : No such file or directory aarch64-poky-linux-gcc: error: : No such file or directory error: command 'aarch64-poky-linux-gcc' failed with exit status 1 src/mlpack/methods/preprocess/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_preprocess_split.dir/build.make:60: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/methods/preprocess/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_preprocess_split' failed make[2]: *** [src/mlpack/methods/preprocess/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_preprocess_split] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory '/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build' CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1387: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/methods/preprocess/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_preprocess_split.dir/all' failed make[1]: *** [src/mlpack/methods/preprocess/CMakeFiles/build_pyx_preprocess_split.dir/all] Error 2 [ 89%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_softmax_regression cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/softmax_regression && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_softmax_regression.dir/link.txt --verbose=1 /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall
-Wextra -ftemplate-depth=1000 -O3 -fopenmp -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DNDEBUG
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wl,-O1
-Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu
-Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_softmax_regression.dir/__/__/bindings/python/generate_pyx_softmax_regression.cpp.o CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_softmax_regression.dir/__/__/bindings/python/print_pyx.cpp.o
-o ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_softmax_regression -rdynamic ../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.2.0 -lrt -larmadillo
-lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_unit_test_framework
-lboost_serialization-mt cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/softmax_regression && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake
-DGENERATE_PYX_PROGRAM=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_softmax_regression
-DPYX_OUTPUT_FILE=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/softmax_regression.pyx
-P /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/git/CMake/GeneratePYX.cmake /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_softmax_regression: /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_softmax_regression: cannot execute binary file make[2]: Leaving directory '/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build' [ 89%] Built target generate_pyx_softmax_regression [ 89%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_knn cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/neighbor_search && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_knn.dir/link.txt --verbose=1 /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall
-Wextra -ftemplate-depth=1000 -O3 -fopenmp -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DNDEBUG
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wl,-O1
-Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu
-Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_knn.dir/__/__/bindings/python/generate_pyx_knn.cpp.o CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_knn.dir/__/__/bindings/python/print_pyx.cpp.o
-o ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_knn -rdynamic ../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.2.0 -lrt -larmadillo
-lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_unit_test_framework
-lboost_serialization-mt cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/neighbor_search && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake
-DGENERATE_PYX_PROGRAM=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_knn
-DPYX_OUTPUT_FILE=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/knn.pyx
-P /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/git/CMake/GeneratePYX.cmake /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_knn: /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_knn: cannot execute binary file make[2]: Leaving directory '/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build' [ 89%] Built target generate_pyx_knn [ 89%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_kfn cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/neighbor_search && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_kfn.dir/link.txt --verbose=1 /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall
-Wextra -ftemplate-depth=1000 -O3 -fopenmp -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DNDEBUG
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wl,-O1
-Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu
-Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_kfn.dir/__/__/bindings/python/generate_pyx_kfn.cpp.o CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_kfn.dir/__/__/bindings/python/print_pyx.cpp.o
-o ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_kfn -rdynamic ../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.2.0 -lrt -larmadillo
-lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_unit_test_framework
-lboost_serialization-mt cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/neighbor_search && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake
-DGENERATE_PYX_PROGRAM=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_kfn
-DPYX_OUTPUT_FILE=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/kfn.pyx
-P /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/git/CMake/GeneratePYX.cmake /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_kfn: /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_kfn: cannot execute binary file make[2]: Leaving directory '/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build' [ 89%] Built target generate_pyx_kfn [ 89%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_krann cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/rann && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_krann.dir/link.txt
--verbose=1 /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall
-Wextra -ftemplate-depth=1000 -O3 -fopenmp -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DNDEBUG
-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53
--sysroot=/builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/h3ulcb  -O2 -pipe -g
-feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wl,-O1
-Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu
-Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_krann.dir/__/__/bindings/python/generate_pyx_krann.cpp.o CMakeFiles/generate_pyx_krann.dir/__/__/bindings/python/print_pyx.cpp.o
-o ../../../../bin/generate_pyx_krann -rdynamic ../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.2.0 -lrt -larmadillo
-lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_unit_test_framework
-lboost_serialization-mt cd /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/methods/rann && /builds/build-h3/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake
-DGENERATE_PYX_PROGRAM=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_krann
-DPYX_OUTPUT_FILE=/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/src/mlpack/bindings/python/mlpack/krann.pyx
-P /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/git/CMake/GeneratePYX.cmake /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_krann: /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build/bin/generate_pyx_krann: cannot execute binary file make[2]: Leaving directory '/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build' [ 89%] Built target generate_pyx_krann make[1]: Leaving directory '/builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/build' Makefile:141: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2 ERROR: oe_runmake failed ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /builds/build-h3/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/mlpack/git-r0/temp/log.do_compile.17361)
```

My recipe looks like this:

```
DEPENDS = "boost armadillo python-native python-setuptools-native
python-pandas-native python-numpy-native python-cython-native
python-pytest-runner-native doxygen-native"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=3cee6555b8c975c14d29687fe7e78038"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/mlpack/mlpack.git;protocol=https \
"
SRCREV = "b8ee319818e6213da4b92cb69dab94b956795401"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake pythonnative

EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DDEBUG:BOOL=OFF \
-DPROFILE:BOOL=OFF \
-DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release \
-DCMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=YES \
-DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=YES \
-DPY_PANDAS:PATH=${STAGING_LIBDIR_NATIVE}/python2.7/site-packages/pandas \
"

do_compile_prepend() {
export STAGING_LIBDIR="${STAGING_LIBDIR}"
export STAGING_INCDIR="${STAGING_INCDIR}"
}
```

Is there something else that needs to be included in my recipe?
Or is the build environment missing something?

Any pointers would really help.

Answer (score 0):

mlpack builds the Python bindings in multiple steps:

- build a `generate_pyx_<name>` program to generate the Cython .pyx file that will be compiled
- run the `generate_pyx_<name>` program and save the output .pyx file
- use Cython and setuptools to generate a .cpp file from the .pyx file then compile it

It's a bit of a roundabout process, but I believe what is happening here is that the `generate_pyx_<name>` programs are being compiled for the device instead of the host, and therefore can't be run to generate the .pyx files.  There won't be a particularly easy way to fix this, unfortunately, because CMake will be compiling the `generate_pyx_<name>` target with the same options you are compiling the rest of the library with (which in your case targets the device).

In order to make this work, you'll need to modify `src/mlpack/bindings/python/CMakeLists.txt`, specifically the line

```
add_executable(generate_pyx_${name}
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/mlpack/bindings/python/generate_pyx_${name}.cpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mlpack/bindings/python/print_pyx.hpp
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mlpack/bindings/python/print_pyx.cpp)
```

and related lines.  In essence you will need to make sure that the CXXFLAGS like `-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a57.cortex-a53` do not get used for that particular target.

Comment: I think if the build system for this package is made to respect CC/CXX variables being passed to it from CMake environment, then it will work. Since it needs the full path. This hypothesis is not tested but you might find a way out through this.

Answer (score 0):

Run "ldd aarch64-poky-linux-gcc" first, check if all the libraries it linked with were existed in your machine, if not the system will tell you "No such file or directory".